# How can i find the most popular searches in Google that contain my keyword?

Tags: seo, google

How can I find a list of the most popular searches in Google that contain my keyword,

E.g If I want the most popular containing "Paris" or "London"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search changes each and every day. Google says that %15 of all searches have never been seen before. There is no way on knowing the future, but you can get a peek into what Google thinks is relevant today.

First: You can use Google Trends found here: http://www.google.com/trends/ Just enter your keywords.

Second: In the search text-box, enter your keywords and various phrases in different ways and study how Google suggests popular searches.

The thing you have to remember is that this is a form of looking backwards. There is nothing you can do about that. Think how people will find your content. But also look how competitive sites that are successful use keywords and what keywords they use. I do not always advise going head-to-head with another site, but clues are clues. Successful sites are by definition popular.

Answer (score 1):

Adwords Keyword Planner will give you rough estimation of the search volume. Note that it will not show data for niche search terms which have a few queries per month.

https://adwords.google.com/KeywordPlanner

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyword tool that extracts data from Google Autocomplete to give you many related searches for a certain keyword.

Google Autocomplete is a feature used in Google Search. Its purpose is to speed up the searches performed by users on Google. The tool  extracts Google suggestions and presents you with a list of related searches

http://keywordtool.io/